# hardcopy of gnuplot.py plot

Tags: python, plot, gnuplot

This is my code:

```
d1 = Gnuplot.Data(x1,y1, with_="lines lt rgb 'red'", title="1")
d2 = Gnuplot.Data(x2,y2, with_="lines lt rgb 'red'", title="2")
d3 = Gnuplot.Data(x3,y3, with_="lines lt rgb 'red'", title="3")
g.title("aaa")
g('set size 1,0.75')
g('set grid')
g('set term x11 2')
g('set logscale x')
g('set xtics 1,2,110')
g('set xrange [1:110]')
g.plot(d1,d2,d3)
g.hardcopy("aaa.png", terminal='png')
```

Both in the temporary plot of gnuplot.py and in the hardcopy, I have a big white strip in the upper part due to the 'set size 1,0.75'. 
Is it possible to avoid this and to have a figure exactly large as the plot?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats, what the command `set size` is for: Change the plot size relative to the total canvas/image size. In order to change the image size, you must use the `size` parameter of the `set terminal` command. Unfortunately, that is not supported by some terminals which are defined in `termdefs.py` of gnuplot-py. As the comment in `termdefs.py` says:

> """Terminal definition file.
>
> This module describes the options available to gnuplot's various
>   terminals.  For the moment, it only supports a few terminals, but the
>   infrastructure is here to add others as they are needed. ...

The `svg` terminal supports the `size` parameter:

```
import Gnuplot
from numpy import *

x1 = arange(1,10)
y1 = arange(1,10)

d1 = Gnuplot.Data(x1,y1, with_="lines lt rgb 'red'", title="1")
g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot()

g.title("aaa")
g('set grid')
g('set logscale x')
g('set xtics 1,2,110')
g.plot(d1)
g.hardcopy("aaa.svg", terminal='svg', size=[800,400])
```

The most flexible way is to pass the raw terminal definition string to gnuplot. Then, the line `g.hardcopy...` becomes:

```
g('set terminal pngcairo size 800,400')
g.set_string('output', 'aaa.png')
g.refresh()
g.set_string('output')
```

That allows you also to use the better `pngcairo` terminal instead of the `png` terminal.